# react-router-Dom: Blank page after redirect multiple user on login in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have two(USER and ADMIN) users in my react project and I want to redirect them to their respected page after a successful login. To achieve this I created a standalone component called `authenticatedRoute.js` and wrap those components by AuthenticatedRoute component. Here are the codes

AuthenticatedRoute.js

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

const AuthenticatedRoute = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
  const history = useHistory();
  var tokenn = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("desta"));
  var user_type = tokenn?.user.roles[0]; //USER or ADMIN
  var loggedIn = tokenn?.user_status; //true
  const redirect = () => {
    try {
      switch (user_type) {
        case "USER":
          return [history.push("/user"), children];
        case "ADMIN":
          return [history.push("/admin"), children];
        default:
          console.log("redirect");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      return [history.push("/signin"), children];
    }
  };

  return (
    <Route
      render={() => {
        return loggedIn ? redirect() : history.push("/signin");
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default AuthenticatedRoute;
```

App.js (minimal code)

```
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./components/Header/Header";
import HeaderLinks from "./components/Header/HeaderLinks";
import Hero from "./components/Header/Hero/Hero";
import Login from "./components/auth/Login";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  useHistory,
} from "react-router-dom";
import SignUp from "./components/auth/SignUp";
import ViewUserProfile from "./components/Admin/ViewUserProfile";
import AdminHeader from "./components/Admin/AdminHeader";
import ManageBusinessType from "./components/Admin/ManageBusinessType";
import ManageCompany from "./components/Admin/ManageCompany";
import UserDashboard from "./components/Users/UserDashboard";
import ViewProfile from "./components/Users/ViewProfile";
import { ResetPassword } from "./components/Users/ResetPassword";
import ChangePassword from "./components/Users/ChangePassword";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import AuthenticatedRoute from "./components/auth/authRoute/AuthenticatedRoute";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <AuthenticatedRoute path="/" exact>
          <Hero />
        </AuthenticatedRoute>
        <AuthenticatedRoute path="/admin" exact>
          <AdminHeader />
        </AuthenticatedRoute>
        <AuthenticatedRoute path="/user" exact>
          <UserDashboard />
        </AuthenticatedRoute>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

After a successful login it redirects me to the right user role page but it's empty page as the screenshot below.

[image]

How can I fix the Issue? **I used react-router-dom@5.3.0**
Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to render the result of a navigation action instead of JSX?

Comment: @DrewReese What is the right way, please correct me? Thanks

Comment: If you've still an issue would be possible for you to create a *running* codesandbox demo of your code that reproduces the blank page issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are rendering the result of a navigation action instead of JSX. `AuthenticatedRoute` should render either a `Route` rendering the routed content or a `Redirect` to the appropriate path.

Example:

If `loggedIn` is falsey, then redirect to `"/signin"`, otherwise check the role the route should have access to, and if the role matches render a `Route` with the props passed through, otherwise redirect to the appropriate user/admin path.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

const AuthenticatedRoute = ({ roles, ...props }) => {
  const tokenn = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("desta"));
  const user_type = tokenn?.user.roles[0]; //USER or ADMIN
  const loggedIn = tokenn?.user_status; //true

  return loggedIn
    ? roles.includes(user_type)
      ? <Route {...props} />
      : <Redirect to={user_type === "USER" ? "/user" : "/admin"} />
    : <Redirect to="/signin" />;
};

export default AuthenticatedRoute;
```

Specify the roles a route should accessible by.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <AuthenticatedRoute path="/admin" roles={["ADMIN"]}>
          <AdminHeader />
        </AuthenticatedRoute>
        <AuthenticatedRoute path="/user" roles={["USER"]}>
          <UserDashboard />
        </AuthenticatedRoute>
        <Route path="/">
          <Hero />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-router-dom-blank-page-after-redirect-multiple-user-on-login-in-react]

Comment: This shows blank page. Same as my implementation.

Comment: @TeshAych I've created a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-blank-page-after-redirect-multiple-user-on-login-in-react-ljuo7s) demo and the protected route logic appears to work as I was expecting. I've also linked it in my answer. Please do check it out. Perhaps it wasn't implemented correctly in your app. We can debug from there.