# What is the best way to make redirect multiple users in react after login?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have two users(ADMIN and User). I want these users redirected to their respected page `/admin` and `/user` respectively otherwise redirect them to `/signin` route. I created a standalone component called `Authenticated` route and wrap components inside of it but I got an empty screen with successful redirect. Here is the codes

AuthenticatedRoute.js

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

const AuthenticatedRoute = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
  const history = useHistory();
  var tokenn = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("desta"));
  var user_type = tokenn?.user.roles[0]; //USER or ADMIN
  var loggedIn = tokenn?.user_status; //true or false
  const redirect = () => {
    try {
      switch (user_type) {
        case "USER":
          return [history.push("/user"), children];
        case "ADMIN":
          return [history.push("/admin"), children];
        default:
          console.log("redirect");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      return [history.push("/signin"), children];
    }
  };

  return (
    <Route
      render={() => {
        return loggedIn ? redirect() : history.push("/signin");
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default AuthenticatedRoute;
```

App.js (minimal code)

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <AuthenticatedRoute path="/" exact>
          <Hero />
        </AuthenticatedRoute>
        <AuthenticatedRoute path="/admin" exact>
          <AdminHeader />
        </AuthenticatedRoute>
        <AuthenticatedRoute path="/user" exact>
          <UserDashboard />
        </AuthenticatedRoute>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
 
  );
}

export default App;
```

Login.js (minimal code)

```
const Login = (props) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const history = useHistory();

  const submit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (email === "") {
      alert("Please enter email");
    } else if (password === "") {
      alert("Please enter password");
    } else if (email.length < 4 || password.length < 5) {
      alert("Email length should be atleast six character");
    } else {
      try {
        const response = await apiClient.auth
          .login({
            username: "helghsdfdlo",
            password: "sdsjfghbdcjh",
          })
          .then(
            (response) => {
              props.set_token(response.data.accessToken);
              props.set_user_data(response.data);
              props.set_user_status({
                approved: response.data.approved,
                loggedIn: true,
                token: response.data.accessToken,
              });
            },
            (err) => {
              alert("Email and password is not valid");
            }
          );
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  };
```

I called `submit` function on a button click as follows inside `Login` component.

```
<button
                onClick={(e) => {
                  submit(e);
                }}
                className="px-6 py-2 mt-4 text-white bg-blue rounded-lg hover:bg-blue-900"
              >
                Login
              </button>
```

When I run my app, Although it redirects to the expected route, it shows me a blank page?

[image]

So what's the best way to achieve this feature, If incase you have experience implementing the same logic before, I am here asking for help.

**I used react-router-dom@5.3.0**

Thanks

Comment: Did my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71758535/8690857) to your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71758374/react-router-dom-blank-page-after-redirect-multiple-user-on-login-in-react) not address this issue?

Comment: It doesn't help, It still shows a blank page. If you spot the mistake It would be great. Thanks

Comment: It's preferable to provide feedback in the original question, and provide any new details, than to ask a new question.